# How can I express scheduling problems in minisat?

Tags: constraint-programming, sat

Minisat is a constraint programming/satisfaction tool, there is a version of Minisat which works here in the browser http://www.msoos.org/2013/09/minisat-in-your-browser/

How can I express a scheduling problem with Minisat? Is there a higher level language which compiles to Minisat which would let me express it?

I mean for solving problems like exam timetabling. http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#examination

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another high level modeling language is Picat (http://picat-lang.org/), which have an option to solve/2 to convert to CNF when using the sat module, e.g. "solve([dump], Vars)". The syntax when using the sat module - as well as for the cp and mip modules - is similar to standard CLP syntax.

For some Picat examples, see my Picat page: http://hakank.org/picat/ .

Comment: I'm learning minizinc, and afaik your site it the best resource (as well as your answers here on SO)... alas, it's unresponsive by some days... Anyway, your [github repo](https://github.com/hakank) is still available. Thanks

Comment: @CapelliC: Thanks for your kind words. My site http://hakank.org/ is down right now, but I do everything I can to fix it as soon as possible. Great that you found the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 4):

[SAT solvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) like [Minisat](http://minisat.se/) or [Cryptominisat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat4/) typically read a clause set of logical `OR` expressions in [Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214338/how-to-convert-to-conjunctive-normal-form). It takes an [encoding](http://jsat.ewi.tudelft.nl/addendum/Bjork_encoding.pdf) step to translate your problem into this CNF format.

[Circuit SAT Solvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_satisfiability_problem) process a nested Boolean expression rather than a `CNF`. But it appears that this type of solvers is nowadays outperformed by the `CNF SAT` Solvers.

Constraint programming solvers like [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/2.0/index.html) use a high level language which is easier to write and to comprehend. Depending on the features being used, [Minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/2.0/index.html) can translate its input language into a `CNF/DIMACS` format suitable for a SAT solver.

Peter Stuckey's paper "[There are no CNF Problems](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/slides/SAT2013-stuckey.pdf)" explains the idea. His [slides](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/slides/SAT2013-stuckey.pdf) also contain some insights on scheduling.

Have a look at [Minizinc examples](http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/) for scheduling written by [Hakan Kjellerstrand](http://www.hakank.org/minizinc/index.html).

Emmanuel Hebrard's [Scheduling and SAT](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/cpaior-2012/uploads/slides%20master%20class/5-scheduling-Hebrard.pdf) is an extensive treatment of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this project few months ago.

It was really interesting to do.

To use miniSAT (or any other SAT solvers), 
you will have to reduce the Scheduling Problem to a SAT problem.

I can recommand you this question that I asked in 3 parts.

[Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983729/class-scheduling-to-boolean-satisfiability-polynomial-time-reduction?lq=1)

[Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction] part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140280/class-scheduling-to-boolean-satisfiability-polynomial-time-reduction-part-2?lq=1)

[Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction] Final Part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251041/class-scheduling-to-boolean-satisfiability-polynomial-time-reduction-final-par)

And you will basically see, step by step, how to transform the Scheduling Problem to a SAT problem that MiniSAT can read and solve :).

Thanks again to @[amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit) who was a very big help in this project.

With this answer, you will be able to solve N rooms with T teachers, who are teaching S subjects to G different group of students :) which is I think, enough for 99% of Scheduling Problems.