# Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction]

Tags: c, algorithm, scheduling, reduction, sat

I have some theoretical/practical problem and I don't have clue for now on how to manage, Here it is:

I create a [SAT solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) able to find a model when one is existing and to prove the contradiction when it's not the case on [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) problems in C using genetics algorithms.

A SAT-problem looks basically like this kind of problem : 
[image]
My goal is to use this solver to find solutions in a lot of different  [NP-completes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) problems. Basically, I translate different problems into SAT, solve SAT with my solver and then transform the solution into a solution acceptable for the original problem.

I already succeed for the N*N Sudoku and also the N-queens problems, but here is my new goal : to reduce the Class Scheduling Problem to SAT but I have no idea how to formalize a class-scheduling problem in order to easily transform it in SAT after.

The goal is obviously, in few months, to generate a picture of a schedule like this one :

[image]

I found this [source-code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23111/Making-a-Class-Schedule-Using-a-Genetic-Algorithm) who is able to solved the class-scheduling but without any reductions to SAT unfortunately :/

I also found some articles about Planning in general (http://www.cs.rochester.edu/users/faculty/kautz/papers/kautz-satplan06.pdf for instance).

But the [planning domain definition language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Domain_Definition_Language) used in this article seems quite too general for me to represents a Class-scheduling problem. :/

Does someone has an idea on how to formalize efficiently a Class-scheduling in order to reduce it to SAT and after, transform the SAT solution (if it exists ^^) into a Class-schedule ?

I'm basically open to any suggestions, I for now have no idea on how to represents, how to reduce the problem, how to transform the SAT-solution into a schedule...

---

**Follow up question**: [Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction] part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140280/572670)

Comment: First, please formalize input and expected output of your class scheduling (or link to somewhere that formalize it)

Comment: it can be anything, that's the problem :  I search the best formalize for the class scheduling problem, and best for me means "the easiest to transform in SAT" :) 

I have no formalized input for now, and my problem is to find one :/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I am going to try and first formalize the problem, and then attempt to reduce it to SAT.

**Define the class scheduling problem as:**

```
Input = { S1,S2,....,Sn | Si = {(x_i1, y_i1), (x_i2, y_i2) , ... , (x_ik, y_ik) | 0 <= x_ij < y_ij <= M } }
```

Informally: The input is a set of classes, each class is a set of (open) intervals in the form (x,y)

(M is some constant that describes the "end of the week")

Output: True if and only if there exists some set:

```
R = { (x_1j1, y_1j1) , ..., (x_njn, y_njn) | for each a,b: (x_aja,y_aja) INTERSECTION (x_bjb,y_bjb) = {} }
```

Informally: true if and only if there is some assignment of intervals such that the intersection between each pair of intervals is empty.

---

**Reduction to SAT:**

Define a boolean variable for each interval, `V_ij`

Based on it, define the formula:

```
F1 = (V_11 OR V_12 OR ... OR V_1(k_1)) AND .... AND (V_n1 OR V_n2 OR ... OR V_n(k_n))
```

Informally, F1 is satisfied if and only if at least one of the interval for each class is "satisfied"

Define `Smaller(x,y) = true` if and only `if x <= y`<sup>1</sup>

We will use it to make sure intervals don't overlap.

Note that if we want to make sure (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) don't overlap, we need:

```
x1 <= y1 <= x2 <= y2 OR  x2 <= y2 <= x1 <= y1
```

Since the input guarantees `x1<=y1, x2<=y2`, it reduces to:

```
y1<= x2 OR y2 <= x1
```

And using our Smaller and boolean clauses:

```
Smaller(y1,x2) OR Smaller(y2,x1)
```

Now, let's define new clauses to handle with it:

For each pair of classes a,b and intervals c,d in them (c in a, d in b)

```
G_{c,d} = (Not(V_ac) OR Not(V_bd) OR Smaller(y_ac,x_bd) OR Smaller(y_bd,x_ac))
```

Informally, if one of the intervals b or d is not used - the clause is satisfied and we are done. Otherwise, both are used, and we must ensure there is no overlap between the two intervals.

This guarantees that if both c,d are "chosen" - they do not overlap, and this is true for each pair of intervals.

Now, form our final formula:

```
F = F1 AND {G_{c,d} | for each c,d}
```

This formula ensures us:

1. For each class, at least one interval is chosen
2. For each two intervals c,d - if both c and d are chosen, they do not overlap.

Small note: This formula allows to chose more than 1 interval from each class, but if there is a solution with some t>1 intervals, you can easily remove t-1 of them without changing correctness of the solution.

At the end, the chosen intervals are the boolean variables V_ij we defined.

---

**Example:**

```
Alebgra = {(1,3),(3,5),(4,6)} Calculus = {(1,4),(2,5)}
```

Define F:

```
F1 = (V1,1 OR V1,2 OR V1,3) AND (V2,1 OR V2,2)
```

Define G's:

```
G{A1,C1} = Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,1) OR  4 <= 1 OR 3 <= 1 //clause for A(1,3) C(1,4)
         = Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,1) OR false = 
         = Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,1)
G{A1,C2} = Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,2) OR  3 <= 2 OR 5 <= 1 // clause for A(1,3) C(2,5)
         = Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,2) OR false = 
         = Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,2)
G{A2,C1} = Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,1) OR  5 <= 1 OR 4 <= 3 //clause for A(3,5) C(1,4)
         = Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,1) OR false = 
         = Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,1)
G{A2,C2} = Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,2) OR  5 <= 2 OR 5 <= 3 // clause for A(3,5) C(2,5)
         = Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,2) OR false = 
         = Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,2)
G{A3,C1} = Not(V1,3) OR Not(V2,1) OR  4 <= 4 OR 6 <= 1 //clause for A(4,6) C(1,4)
         = Not(V1,3) OR Not(V2,1) OR true= 
         = true
G{A3,C2} = Not(V1,3) OR Not(V2,2) OR  6 <= 2 OR 5 <= 4 // clause for A(4,6) C(2,5)
         = Not(V1,3) OR Not(V2,2) OR false = 
         = Not(V1,3) OR Not(V2,2)
```

Now we can show our final formula:

```
    F = (V1,1 OR V1,2 OR V1,3) AND (V2,1 OR V2,2) 
        AND  Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,1) AND Not(V1,1) OR Not(V2,2)
        AND  Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,1) AND Not(V1,2) OR Not(V2,2)
        AND  true AND Not(V1,3) OR Not(V2,2)
```

The above is satisfied only when:

```
V1,1 = false
V1,2 = false
V1,3 = true
V2,1 = true
V2,2 = false
```

And that stands for the schedule: Algebra=(4,6); Calculus=(1,4), as desired.

---

(1) can be computed as a constant to the formula pretty easily, there are polynomial number of such constants.

Comment: I really hope I made no mistake, this was not a trivial reduction, please comment if you see any issue

Comment: Thank you very much :) but I have to admit, I don't think I get everything you said :D 

Your formalize is indeed the simpliest and so, the better to transform in SAT :) I understand how to get at the end the planning from the SAT solution. 

But can you give a little example, like 2 classes and 3 intervals. I understand that there will be 2*3 = 6 booleans variables; But what will look like the CNF file ?

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail I updated the answer with a simple example. with 2 classes and 3,2 intervals. Note that the number of variables in this case is 3+2. The number of clauses is almost `O(#variables^2)`.

Comment: Thanks again :) I was working in the same time on your ideas and I get it now ^^ (I answer maybe too fast before thinking ^^)

But really, I'm totally impressed, your method is so elegant, simple and works perfectly :)

Thank you for your example, it illustred what I've understand :) just to be perfectly sure :)

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail I wouldn't say "simple", took quite a lot of time to think about it, and even more to formalize it. It is simple to program though :)

Comment: Yep :P when I said simple I mean the algorithm  behind :p for sure not the thinking-process :) anyway : thanks again ! greetings from France !

Comment: Hi @Amit,I code your method and it works perfectly for one day (from N to M). But I generalize your method to not only 1 day (from N to M) but to 1 week (from N to 5*M) and there is an issue : the problem is not constrainted enough, so sometimes it says that twice the same class is true (but it should not). 

I think it came from the fact that in CNF it says Vi_1 OR Vi_2 OR ... But there is nothing to say that if Vi_1 is true, then Vi_j should be false ... : / 
Do you have an idea on how to fix this ? :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72840/discussion-between-valentin-montmirail-and-amit).

Comment: q= (-_- ) Hmm... no source-code no fun, what is `S1`, `x_i1` and `x_ij`??? at least, plz someone edit this and **replace Sudo-code with actual Math and/or Algebra** (like, I still don't get underscore meaning)