# Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction] part 2

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, np-complete, np, sat

I asked few days ago, a question about how to transform a University Class Scheduling Problem into a Boolean Satisfiability Problem.

([Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983729/class-scheduling-to-boolean-satisfiability-polynomial-time-reduction))

I got an answer by @Amit who was very elegant and easy to code. 
Basically, his answer was like this : instead of considering courses, he considered time-intervals.

So for the i-th course, he just indicted all the possible intervals for this course. And we obtain a solution when there is at least 1 true-interval for every course and when no interval overlap an other.

This methods works very well when we consider only courses and nothing else. I generalize it by encoding the room inside the interval.

for example, instead of [8-10] to say that a course can happen between 8am and 10am.

I used [0.00801 - 0.01001] to say that a course can happen between 8am and 10am in the room 1.

I'm sure that you are currently wandering "why use double ?" well, because here come my problem :

To continue to generalize this method, I encode also the n° of the teacher in this interval.

I used [1.00801 - 1.01001] to say that a course can happen between 8am and 10am in the room 1 and be taught by the teacher n°1.

Here is what I got for now :

[image: Illustration of what my solver give me in output]

like this [1.008XX - 1.010XX] can happen in the same time as [2.008YY - 2.010YY], which is true, if the teacher 1 is teaching in the room X between 8am and 10am, the teacher 2 can teach also in Y between 8am and 10am, if and only if the room is available.

The problem is : with this method I cannot assure that XX and YY will be different and that YY will be available, because [1.008XX - 1.010XX] don't overlap [2.008XX - 2.010XX], so for now, the solver consider this possible.

And I still don't have any clue on how to assure this, by using this interval-method... 
I need a way to encode {Interval, room and teacher-id} in order that :

- a teacher cannot be in 2 places in the same interval.
- there cannot be 2 teachers in the same room for the same interval.
- there is a least 1 interval true by course.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Best regards !

---

**Follow up question:** [Class Scheduling to Boolean satisfiability [Polynomial-time reduction] Final Part](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29251041/572670)

Comment: I think this question is too broad for SO. I'm not sure what the exact issue is or what the precise question is.

Comment: Think I have an idea how to solve it, hope I will have time to formalize it later on today. Also: Yay, my favorite question part B!

Comment: @MattKo, basically, the issue is : how, with an intervals representation, formalize all the constraint about rooms, teachers and courses. for now, all the constraint for courses and rooms are already done, I just don't know how to formalize : "a teacher cannot be in 2 rooms in the same time", "there cannot be 2 teachers in the same room in the same time" :)

Comment: I'm sure amit will tell you how to do this with a SAT solver, but you might take a look at constraint solvers with more expressive constraint languages.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I  totally agree :) but all the challenge came from the fact that I use my own SAT solver for this, and I want to compare results with friends who use this kind of problems but with CSP solver :) 

In fact, all my trouble came from this, I think too much in CSP for this kind of problem and I don't see how to transform it directly in SAT easily... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is extension of [Part 1's answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28985603/572670)r, and uses the same notations when possible.

Ok, assume each interval is assigned to one teacher (if more than one teacher can take the interval, just have multiple instances of it, with different teachers per instance), so to indicate teacher `t` teaches in a classroom `p` at time `x` to `y`, we can use the old variable that this class is given - `V_{i,j}` - for the class and interval.

For each teacher `t` , and for each pair of intervals `c=(x1,y1)`, `d=(x2,y2)` in classes (a,b) the teacher might participate in, add the clause:

```
Q_{t,i,j} = Not(V_ac) OR Not(V_bd) OR Smaller(y1,x2) OR Smaller(y2,x1)
```

Intuitively, the above clause guarantees a teacher cannot be in the same time in two places - no intervals overlap that the same teacher is assigned to them.

By chaining each pair `(i,j)` for each teacher `t` with AND to the original formula, it satisfies your first constraint - `a teacher cannot be in 2 places in the same interval.` - since each teacher cannot be in two places at the same time.

Your second constraint `there cannot be 2 teachers in the same room for the same interval.` is also satisfied by the fact that there cannot be two classes that overlap the time and class.

The 3rd constraint `there is a least 1 interval true by course.` is satisfied by the `F1` clause, since you have to choose at least one interval (with one teacher assigned) for each course.

Comment: Again Amit, Thanks you so much, I just finished to code your interpretation of this teacher-feature :) and it gives exactly the expected result ^^.